# is it possible to have different behaviors for the same constructor?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I'm writing an SQL interpreter. I need to distinguish between ill-formed expressions at compile time, and run-time errors.

I'll give you an example of something that should be well-formed, but possibly fails at run-time.

```
SELECT $ [ColumnName "first_name" `AS` "name"] `FROM` TABLE "people.csv" `WHERE` (ColumnName "age" `Gte` LiteralInt 40)
```

I'd like to focus in on the expression:

```
(ColumnName "age" `Gte` LiteralInt 40)
```

This should pass the type checker. But, say "age" did not contain something that could be expressed as a `LiteralInt`.

So I would want `Gte` to produce something like `IO Bool` (not minding exception handling for now).

But I wouldn't always need `Gte` to produce an `IO Bool`. In the event I had something like this:

`` (LiteralInt 40 `Gte` LiteralInt 10) `` I just need a Bool.
or something like this:
`` (LiteralInt 40 `Gte` LiteralBool True) `` needs to fail at compile time.

So, I've been toying around with data families and  GADTs, and have gone down many dead ends that would just serve to confuse the situation if I explicated them.

Does my problem make sense, and if so is there a path of inquiry I can traverse that will lead to a solution?

Comment: What would you actually *gain* by having some expressions return `Bool` instead of `IO Bool`?

Comment: Type-safe SQL interfaces? There's an example in [_The Power of Pi_](https://cs.ru.nl/~wouters/Publications/ThePowerOfPi.pdf) and a Haskell translation in [the `singletons` paper](http://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2012/singletons/paper.pdf). The big idea is to declare the schema upfront, and check it matches the actual schema upon opening the DB connection.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I'm going down the rabbit hole. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I would want `Gte` to produce something like `IO Bool` (not minding exception handling for now).
>
> But I wouldn't always need `Gte` to produce an `IO Bool`.

That is not possible (nor indeed desirable). `Gte` will have to always return the same type. Also, you probably want to separate the construction of your query from its execution...

> or something like this: `` (LiteralInt 40 `Gte` LiteralBool True) `` needs to fail at compile time.

Now *that* is much more reasonable. If you decide to go down that path, you can even customize the type errors GHC reports with the new [`TypeError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:TypeError) feature. However, sticking to a simple example involving just `LiteralInt`, `LiteralBool` and `Gte`, you could do something like the following with just GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Expr a where
  LiteralInt :: Int -> Expr Int
  LiteralBool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Gte :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Bool
  Add :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  ColumnName :: String -> Expr a
```

Then, the following would all compile:

```
ColumnName "age" `Gte` LiteralInt 40
LiteralInt 40 `Gte` LiteralInt 10
(LiteralInt 40 `Add` ColumnName "age") `Gte` LiteralInt 10
```

while the following would not:

```
LiteralInt 40 `Gte` LiteralBool True
LiteralInt 40 `Add` LiteralBool True
```

> But, say "age" did not contain something that could be expressed as a `LiteralInt`.

You *could* potentially make this also compile time if you knew your schema at compile time and you wanted to do lots of type-hackery. The simpler solution would be just to make the error handling happen when you execute your query. So you would have a function looking something like

```
evalExpr :: Expr a -> ExceptT e IO a
```

And you would probably perform the appropriate checks concerning the types of columns here.