# Bringing "The Singletons Paper" up to date. How can I implement the AChar datatype using singleton library

Tags: haskell, singleton, dependent-type

Thanks to [Benjamin Hodgson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson), I have started to implement a type-safe SQL-Interface, begun in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683737/is-it-possible-to-have-different-behaviors-for-the-same-constructor) stackoverflow question.

As advised, I have started to read [the singleton paper](http://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2012/singletons/paper.pdf). I find that seeing working code helps a lot, and endeavored to see the supplied [code](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~eir/papers/2012/singletons/code.tar.gz) work. However, the code is three years old, and needs some updating. Great! Now I get to learn something. Here's step one, removing the promoted type AChar with type-literal strings.

from the original code in `singletons-examples/DatabaseStar.hs`

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-incomplete-patterns #-}
{-# Language PolyKinds, DataKinds, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies,
    GADTs, TypeOperators, RankNTypes, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances,
    FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module DatabaseStar where

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.CustomStar
import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
-- A re-definition of Char as an algebraic data type.
-- This is necessary to allow for promotion and type-level Strings.
  data AChar = CA | CB | CC | CD | CE | CF | CG | CH | CI
             | CJ | CK | CL | CM | CN | CO | CP | CQ | CR
             | CS | CT | CU | CV | CW | CX | CY | CZ
             deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

-- A named attribute in our database
  data Attribute a = Attr [AChar] a

-- A schema is an ordered list of named attributes
  data Schema a = Sch [Attribute a]
  |]
```

I found `AChar` to be unsatisfying, and soon realized it was no longer needed.

But I am not sure how to implement type-level `Strings` for this use case. Could someone provide links for me to investigate, and/or hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe type-level "strings" already exist - they go by the name [`Symbol`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol).

```
ghci> :set +t -XTypeInType
ghci> import GHC.TypeLits
ghci> import Data.Proxy
ghci> Proxy :: Proxy "I'm a type level string!"
Proxy
it :: Proxy "I'm a type level string!"
```

That said, I think `singleton` still doesn't play well with these. The problem is that they lack string-like behaviour (like being able to extract characters or make a string from characters). I believe the best solution is still the ugly one of redeclaring characters.